# 320gb hdd all ubuntu, want to partition and add win 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

```
blkid=
/dev/sda1: UUID="05cd7e6a-caf1-44bc-9900-92ec14c5ea34" TYPE="ext2"  
/dev/sda5: UUID="J450yI-3go9-4Ps2-kdQm-lNH7-Go3J-FrvhOm" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="9cd5d111-ec03-4298-803a-a65fdc8790ea" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb: LABEL="UDF Volume" TYPE="udf" /*This is Win 7 install*/
```

This is system monitor file system output:

```
Device                         Directory     Type  Total   Available
/dev/mappper/ubuntu--vg-root   /             ext4  310.6GB 240.1GB
/dev/sda1                      /boot         ext2  246.8MB 135.3MB
/dev/sdb                       /media/name/udf     3.2GB   0 bytes
```

I would like to partition the first drive and install win 7 from sd card at `/dev/sdb`
I am novice level, but am comfortable and competent to cut and paste into terminal.
Open for suggestions for another method, no floppy drive but plenty of blank cd's and usb drives and sd card capacity.

Comment: This is LVM not standard partitions. So you have to use LVM tools to shrink the LVM and then shrink the partition the LVM is inside. Then you should have unallocated space to create a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. Since the LVM is inside a logical partition you move to shift unallocated back to primary or outside extended partition. This will not be particularly easy as you have lots of different tools needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do the following:

1. Boot into Ubuntu or GParted Live CD/DVD
2. (Ubuntu only) Install GParted (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted)
3. Graphically shrink the Ubuntu to partition the amount you want to use with Windows
4. Reboot, boot into Windows 7 disc/card/what have you
5. Partition the now completely unused space via installer and install Windows 7

[WikiHow GParted Live CD/DVD Guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Gparted)

You may need to recover your bootloader in order to be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows at boot. Official [Guide to Repairing Bootloader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

*Always backup any files you want to keep before partitioning, stuff happens.*